# Android Expressions in a String

Tags: java, android, parsing, expression

Hello I am developing a new feature of my app where I have to write a String parser.
I am still designing the solution and not sure what is the best approach for it.

**Example :**
         I can get a String looking like "`!CALC(${value-1}*!CALC(${value-2}-{value-3}))`"
The "`!`" sign indicates the beginning of a function and the  "`&`" sign indicates the beginning of a parameter.
As you can see I can also have a function call inside another function and the result of that function to be treated as a parameter afterwards.

I have already implemented the method for performing the CALC but I am still not a 100% sure how to properly parse the String. Any suggestions or examples will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I wrote to parse a !CALC string. It works for the four basic operators. Note that I added a $ for every value. Where you wrote `${value-2}-{value-3}`, I wrote `${value-2}-${value-3}`. In the example in the code below, the result is `12*4-2`. Only minor changes have to be made to the code to perform the calculation as well. Note: this only works for the CALC command. You can surely make improvements here.

```
private void parse()
{
    String expression = "!CALC($12*!CALC($4-$2))";
    String result = this.parseExpression(expression);
}

private String parseExpression(String expression)
{
    String[] parts = this.splitCalc(expression);
    String numberOne;
    String numberTwo;

    if(parts[0].startsWith("$"))
        numberOne = parts[0].substring(1);
    else
        numberOne = this.parseExpression(parts[0]);

    if(parts[2].startsWith("$"))
        numberTwo = parts[2].substring(1);
    else
        numberTwo = this.parseExpression(parts[2]);

    return numberOne+parts[1]+numberTwo;
}

//splits an expression in the form of !CALC(a*b) in ["a", "*", "b"]
private String[] splitCalc(String expression)
{
    expression = expression.substring(6, expression.length() - 1);
    String[] expressions = new String[3];

    if(expression.startsWith("$"))
    {
        int valueStopIndex = this.getValueStopIndex(expression, 0);
        expressions[0] = expression.substring(0, valueStopIndex);
        expressions[1] = expression.substring(valueStopIndex, valueStopIndex+1);
        expressions[2] = expression.substring(valueStopIndex+1);
    }
    else //starts with !CALC
    {
        int calcStopIndex = this.getCalcCloseIndex(expression, 6);
        expressions[0] = expression.substring(0, calcStopIndex);
        expressions[1] = expression.substring(calcStopIndex, calcStopIndex+1);
        expressions[2] = expression.substring(calcStopIndex+1);
    }

    return expressions;
}

//returns the index of the closing bracket ')'
private int getCalcCloseIndex(String fullExpression, int startIndex)
{
    int level = 0;

    char[] chars = fullExpression.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    {
        if(chars[i] == '(')
        {
            level++;
        }
        else if(chars[i] == ')')
        {
            level--;
            if(level == 0 && i >= startIndex)
                return i;
        }
    }

    return startIndex;
}

private int getValueStopIndex(String fullExpression, int startIndex)
{
    int firstOperatorIndex = fullExpression.length();
    int currentOperatorIndex = fullExpression.indexOf('+');
    if(currentOperatorIndex >= startIndex && currentOperatorIndex < firstOperatorIndex)
        firstOperatorIndex = currentOperatorIndex;
    currentOperatorIndex = fullExpression.indexOf('-');
    if(currentOperatorIndex >= startIndex && currentOperatorIndex < firstOperatorIndex)
        firstOperatorIndex = currentOperatorIndex;
    currentOperatorIndex = fullExpression.indexOf('*');
    if(currentOperatorIndex >= startIndex && currentOperatorIndex < firstOperatorIndex)
        firstOperatorIndex = currentOperatorIndex;
    currentOperatorIndex = fullExpression.indexOf('/');
    if(currentOperatorIndex >= startIndex && currentOperatorIndex < firstOperatorIndex)
        firstOperatorIndex = currentOperatorIndex;
    return firstOperatorIndex;
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution but it solves only that specific expression.
I have to make something that will solve any possible expression that uses the same syntax ( function !<name>(...)
and the closing bracket marks the end of the function , parameter ${<name>} where the closing curly brace marks its end)
The problem for me is writing something that can have N number of nested functions (basically traversing inside out)